# Authenticate/register user in step 2/3 of Form Wizard in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I'd like to collect user information in the following way:

1. first ask for general information upon showing the form
2. ask her to signup/login
3. Ask for some complimentary information
4. and finally assign her `user` to all these information and save it to db

My so far finding is that one can only protect a wizard using a `LoginRequiredMixin`/`login_required` on the view function, e.g.:

```
@login_required
def wizard(request, **kwargs):
    forms = (
             ('painter', PainterForm),
             # it should show a login page here
             ('outcome', PainterOutcomeForm),
             )
    wizard = PainterWizard.as_view(forms, url_name='wizard_step')
    return wizard(request, **kwargs)
```

Which, will translate to step 2, step 1, step 3 & 4 of the wizard.

Is there a solution for this? I am desparate on finding a solution for this problem with many hours wasted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override `dispatch` method and return `PermissionDenied` after checking for the current step.

Remember, you need to run the parent first, since `dispatch` is filling up instance with all needed wizard data.

Pseudocode:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(MyWizardView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    if self.steps.current == '2'
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            raise PermissionDenied

    return response
```